# Finding the Power Spectral Density of $x(t)$

Tags: power-spectral-density, homework

Consider a binary signal $x(t) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}a_ns(t-nT_b)$ where,
$$
s(t) = \left\{\begin{matrix}
 1& t\in[0, T_b) \\ 
 0& o.w.
\end{matrix}\right.
$$
and

$$
a_n = \left\{\begin{matrix}
 +A& \text{with a prior probability of } P_{A^+}\\ 
 -A & \text{with a prior probability of } 1 - P_{A^+}
\end{matrix}\right.
$$

How can I find the power spectral density(PSD) of $x(t)$?

Steps i have tried,

I started by calculating the autocorrelation function of $\{ a_n\}$
$$
R_a(k) = E[a^*_na + n + k] = \left[( P_{A^+})|a_n|^2 + (1 - P_{A^+})|a_n|^2 \right] \delta(k) = A^2 \delta(k)
$$

Then I calculate the PSD of $x(t)$

$$
S_x(f) = \frac{1}{T_b}S_a(f)|S(f)|^2 = \frac{A^2}{T}|S(f)|^2 = A^2T\text{sinc}^2(fT)
$$

But I am told that the answer is a constant value of A. Not sure if I am understanding the problem correctly or is the answer wrong?

Comment: Add a "homework" tag if this is the case. Also, I can't follow your reasoning for Ra[k] (the result is incorrect BTW). And the PSD is not constant as you've been told.

Comment: I was following an example in the textbook where $a_n$ is a qpsk symbol and $R_a[k]$ is the expected value of $|a_n|^2$ times $\delta(t)$